# How does adding a random byte *increase* duplicates?

Tags: python

Here is a Python function for generating my own specific type for UUID (It's a long story for why I can't use `uuid.uuid1()`):

```
def uuid():
    sec = hex(int(time()))[2:]
    usec = hex(datetime.now().microsecond)[2:]
    rand = hex(choice(range(256)))[2:]

    return upper(sec + usec + rand)
    # 534AD79CDF1D27
```

Now, let's let that run for a long period of time, and see if we find any duplicates:

```
UUIDs   Duplicates
100000  2
200000  8
300000  8
400000  8
500000  8
600000  9
700000  9
800000  9
900000  9
1000000     10
1100000     14
1200000     14
1300000     14
1400000     17
1500000     17
1600000     18
1700000     21
1800000     24
1900000     24
2000000     27
```

Yep!  Nearly 30 duplicates in fact...  Now, here's a new function without the random byte at the end:

```
def uuid():
    sec = hex(int(time()))[2:]
    usec = hex(datetime.now().microsecond)[2:]

    return upper(sec + usec)
    #534ADA2AC4A41
```

Let's see how many duplicates we get now:

```
UUIDs   Duplicates
100000  0
200000  0
300000  0
400000  0
500000  0
600000  0
700000  0
800000  0
900000  0
1000000     0
1100000     0
1200000     0
1300000     0
1400000     0
1500000     0
1600000     0
1700000     0
1800000     0
1900000     0
2000000     0
```

Well, would you look at that?  Not a single duplicate!  Also, if you're curious how I'm determining the number of duplicates, here is the code for that:

```
len([x for x, y in Counter(ids).items() if y > 1])
```

Now, on to the actual question:  **How does *adding* a randomly generated byte *increase* the number of duplicates?**

Comment: My intuition, which may very well be wrong, is that as time goes on you are guaranteed to never get the same time again, which causes you to generate predictable, but collision-free uuids. When you add the random number you can go "back" in time and hit a previous uuid, which is impossible without the random number.

Comment: @sortfiend, I thought the same, but he is not actually adding random number, but appending it - these are strings not integers.

Comment: The only way you would get duplicates in that case is if you managed to generate two uuid's that grabbed the same microsecond AND generated the same random number in the same time(). Now I'm not so sure why this is...

Comment: Can you try to provide simple, but complete executable program that shows this behavior?

Comment: @zch I simply ran the fictions above on a while loop, but if you like, I've provided the script I'm using to test for duplicates here: http://pastebin.com/H6GCb6gP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `hex()` without zero-padding. `hex(int(time()))` is basically always 8 nybbles long because it increments quite slowly, so that first part is constant length. Nybble here refers to a single hex digit.

But, `hex(datetime.now().microsecond)` is *not* a constant length. It will vary between 1 nybble (up to 9 us) up to 5 nybbles (for 999999 us). Without the "random byte", this isn't a problem because you can get the microsecond value uniquely by truncating off the seconds.

However, your "random byte" is also produced without any padding! So, you can end up generating a 1 nybble random byte, or a 2 nybble random byte. So, you will end up potentially creating more conflicts because you can generate the same uuid with e.g. a 3-nybble usec and a 2-nybble rand, as with a 4-nybble usec and a 1-nybble rand. So, for example, these two are collisions:

```
usec = 0xabc
rand = 0xde
```

and

```
usec = 0xabcd
rand = 0xe
```

To fix this, pad all of your strings. This is really easy to do with `format`:

```
usec = format(datetime.now().microsecond, '05x') # hexify `microsecond` with 5 fixed hex digits
```

Comment: You're right!  Here is the version of the function that works:  http://pastebin.com/TTim7dSV

Answer (score 1):

`usec` will be between 1 and 5 characters and `rand` will be between 1 and 2 characters, so it's not too surprising that concatenating the two (within the same second) will produce collisions.

For example, `usec = '12'` and `rand = '3'` yields the same string as `usec = '1'` and `rand = '23'` (i.e. `'123'`).

You could avoid this by left-padding them so that `usec` is always exactly 5 characters and `rand` is always exactly 2 characters.